# Google font api / json /php /json_decode

Tags: php, json, google-font-api

I have this json var from google api :

```
$json='
{
 "kind": "webfonts#webfontList",
 "items": [ 
{
   "kind": "webfonts#webfont",
   "family": "Jockey One",
   "variants": [
    "400"
   ],
   "subsets": [
    "latin",
    "latin-ext"
   ]
  },
  {
   "kind": "webfonts#webfont",
   "family": "Josefin Sans",
   "variants": [
    "100",
    "100italic",
    "300",
    "300italic",
    "400",
    "400italic",
    "600",
    "600italic",
    "700",
    "700italic"
   ],
   "subsets": [
    "latin"
   ]
  },
....
 ]
}';
```

How can i decode $json with php in order to display informations like this :

- Font 1 : family - variant - subsets
- Font 2 : family - variant - subsets

Ex for the second item :

- Font family : Josefin Sans  | variants : 100, 100italic,300...|subsets : latin

Thank you

Comment: Use `json_decode()`. Then walk through the array

Comment: could you give an example of the php code using json_decode ?
Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$data = json_decode($json,true);
$items = $data['items'];
$i = 0;
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $i++;
    $str = 'Font '.$i.' '.$item['family'].' Subsets:';
    foreach ($item['variants'] as $variant) {
      $str .= ' '.$variant.' ';
    }
    $str.= ' Variants';
    foreach ($item['subsets'] as $subset) {
      $str .= ' '.$subset;
    }
    echo $str.'<br />';
}
```

This does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the most comfortable way is to create a data structure in your PHP code, and you will decode this JSON to a list of items from this type.
Then, it will be very easy to iterate this list and get the data that you want.

The data structure that I'm talking about is something that will contain

```
String : kind
String : family
List<String> : variants
List<String> : subsets
```

hope this helps...

Comment: Maybe it can help but i m a beginner in php.