# How can I get the list of all google fonts WITHOUT using the API key?

Tags: php, wordpress, google-font-api

Im making a wordpress theme with a feature to allow users to choose their own fonts from Google. Obviously because this is a wordpress theme there is no way to create a new API key for each installation.

All I need is the list of fonts in alphabetical order.

Bonus points if someone gives me a way to group them by category!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the [developer API](https://developers.google.com/webfonts/docs/developer_api). You can query it for a list of the fonts. I'm not sure it categorises them, but you do get a bunch of details.

**Update:**

You only need an API key beyond usage limits, so depending on how many calls you make, you could just [parse this JSON](https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts).

**Further update:**

Seems that you do now need an API key to make calls to the Developer API.

Comment: ahh ok, I just found this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463760/google-font-api-json-php-json-decode) which helps too, so I can format it how I want. Now, is there a way to grab that json directly from that link instead of copying it into a file?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php, then use json_decode to put it into an array and should be good to go.

Comment: [This](http://worknotes.scripting.com/february2012/22612ByDw/listOfGoogleFonts) shows a list of available google fonts updated to the hour.

Comment: I get permission denied for "parse this JSON". The link in the comment above me is also expired.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Seems you need an API key now - but they're free to obtain from the developer console.

Answer (score 2):

I would build my list with minimum values I need and store it locally.
You can store it as json string on your page.

For example open in browser:
https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=YOUR-API-KEY

```
var allGoogleFonsts = JSON.parse(JSON_RESULT);

var fontFamilyWithCategory = allGoogleFonsts.items.map(fontItem => {
    return {
        family: fontItem.family,
        category: fontItem.category,
    };
});

var groupBy = function(xs, key, value) {
  return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x[value]);
    return rv;
  }, {});
};

var fontFamilyByCategory = groupBy(fontFamilyWithCategory, 'category', 'family');
```

Now you can store and use it without api calls:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(fontFamilyByCategory));
```